# losing connection on new ubuntu installation on dell notebook

Tags: networking, dell

Today i've installed ubuntu on my dell inspiron notebook and now i'm losing internet connection. Before install ubuntu I disable dell RST and set to AHCI mode. I cant spend more than 3 minutes using the internet, i dont get a connection loss message or something like that, but the pages dont load for a few seconds before returning to normal.
If you need some information, plz tell me and i'll give to you.

Edit: i'm sending ping to google.com from my terminal and i'm not losing packges in any moment.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the hardware you're using? Dell has made a lot of different Inspiron's over the last 20 years. Is the wireless card an internal device? A USB dongle? Something else? More details will make it easier for someone to identify a possible solution.